# Data structure / Algorithm for section lookup

Tags: algorithm

What kind of datastructure / algorithm should I use for looking up which section currently in, given a list of endpoints of each section?

For example, if I have a webpage with section headers and content,

- Introduction (ends at 100px)
- Section 1    (ends at 350px)
- Section 2    (ends at 700px)
- Conclusion   (ends at 1200px)
- comments

and I'm currently at 130px, it should return that I'm currently in "Section 1".

## Option 1

Binary search through array of endpoints

```py
from bisect import bisect_left

arr = [100, 350, 700, 1200]
pos = bisect_left(arr, 130, 0, arr[-1])
```

However, this could still take O(log n) for every change in position.

## Option 2

Hash table lookup of current location,

```py
lookup = {0: "Introduction"
          1: "Introduction"
          ...
          10: "Section 1"
          11: "Section 1"
          ...
         }
section = lookup[130/10]
```

This is fast, but it wastes a lot of space

---

Is there a general data structure / algorithm that deals with this type of problem?

Comment: `Section` number can't be very large, I think a simple array is OK

Comment: How many sections you have? Is it possible that sections will be created/updated/deleted in run time?

Comment: I just used sections on a webpage as an example, but it's actually used for larger arrays, so a general algorithm would be nice. @Толя I haven't thought of modifying it in real time, but it'd be great to have a good complexity for that too.

Comment: @LeeChou in that case if you have a larger scenario in mind too and want a generic solution then the n-k tree is the way to go;  it's complexity for both inserting and searching is O(lg n) and its space efficiency is O(n).

Comment: A hash where the keys are sequential integers doesn't make sense.  If you go that route, just use an array so lookups don't require hashing an integer, and you'll get higher storage density.

Answer (score 2):

I like your first option, binary searches are very efficient for scanning and as you say the second option is not space efficient.

The traditional and very generic solution that scales in computer graphics is a [2d k-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), which creates a tree that can be looked up by coordinates without wasting memory.  Specifically its search, removal and insert complexities are all O(log n) and its space complexity is O(n).

Given that you are only doing one axis though and a web page will tend to have 1-100 sections (and is unlikely to have thousands, let alone millions, or billions of sections) then I would personally consider going with a very simple array and then move to a more complex k-tree when there is a measurable benefit/need.  If you are writing this in C or another language that gives you some control on the memory layout, then an array of structures would be exceptionally fast to scan due to the design of modern cpus and memory hierarchies (specifically prefetchers and caching).

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest and effective it is use a binary search with O(LogN) complexity.

You second option have better complexity O(1), but have disadvantage with pre-population. Pre-population for binary search more simpler.

**Both these approaches is best if you not update sections in run time**.

Data structures required if you need add/delete/update sections run time.
Because you approaches required update pre-populated data with O(N). It means Update/Add/Delete section operations can take up to O(N).